# Change font type of CharacterRun

Tags: java, apache-poi, doc, hwpf

I have a document (.doc) that I've generated using Apache POI with HWPF and I want to change the font type. I'm guessing that the place to change it would be on the character runs inside each paragraph.

CharacterRun has methods such as `.setBold()` `.setColor()` and `.getFontName()` but there isn't any method to set the font that I've been able to find.

In XWPF there is a `.setFontFamily()` but is there a way to do the same thing with HWPF?

```
Range after = doc.getRange();
int numParagraphs = after.numParagraphs();

for(int i = 0; i < numParagraphs; i++){
    Paragraph paragraph = after.getParagraph(i);

    int charRuns = paragraph.numCharacterRuns();
    for(int j = 0; j < charRuns; j++){
        int size = 9;
        CharacterRun run = paragraph.getCharacterRun(j);
        run.setFontSize(size*2); // In half sizes.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method for changing the font type on a CharacterRun is `.setFtcAscii()` which changes the font to one of the document's embedded fonts. The document I was using had the font table below.

```
╔═══╦═════════════════╗
║   ║ Font Family     ║
╠═══╬═════════════════╣
║ 0 ║ Times New Roman ║
║ 1 ║ Symbol          ║
║ 2 ║ Arial           ║
║ 3 ║ Calibri         ║
║ 4 ║ Courier New     ║
║ 5 ║ Cambria Math    ║
╚═══╩═════════════════╝
```

I needed to change the font to `Courier New` so I used:

```
run.setFtcAscii(4);
```

--

Other documents may have different font tables so I created a for-loop that set the font index and then printed out font name using `.getFontName()`

Also, I found that `run.setFtcOther(int)` does the same thing as `run.setFtcAscii(int)`

See: (0x4A4F)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd947480(v=office.12).aspx